# Clicking on PictureBox with AutoIt ControlClick fails

Tags: windows, vb6, controls, picturebox, autoit

I am trying to automatically click a PictureBox control from an old VB6 application using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Window Info finds a control with class `ThunderRT6PictureBoxDC` and `ID 15`, and AutoIt successfully hides it if I run...

```
ControlHide($class, "", "[ID:15]")
```

However, when I try to click it using:

```
ControlClick($class, "", "[ID:15]")
```

...nothing happens - and `@error` is unset.

Clicking using `MouseClick` with the control coordinates works, but then I have to make sure that the window isn't covered by anything.

Does anyone know why nothing happens, and what I can do to workaround without resorting to `MouseClick`?

Comment: I would break out Spy++ to see what messages AutoIt is sending to the PictureBox control, and see how that varies from what you want to actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Are you sure MouseClick requires the window point being clicked to be visible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know AutoIt, but possibly this is because the control is a PictureBox rather than a button, so Windows doesn't support the concept of a "click" on this control. Can't think of any alternative workaround.